# TCL Dict to JSON

Tags: json, dictionary, tcl

I am trying to convert a dict into JSON format and not seeing any easy method using TclLib Json Package. Say, I have defined a dict as follows :

```
set countryDict [dict create USA {population 300 capital DC} Canada {population 30 capital Ottawa}]
```

I want to convert this to json format as shown below:

```
{
  "USA": {
    "population": 300,
    "captial": "DC"
  },
  "Canada": {
    "population": 30,
    "captial": "Ottawa"
  }
}
```

("population" is number and capital is string). I am using TclLib json package (https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcllib+JSON) . Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems with the “go straight there” approach that you appear to be hoping for:

1. Tcl's type system is extremely different to JSON's; in Tcl, *every* value is a (subtype of) string, but JSON expects objects, arrays, numbers and strings to wholly different things.
2. The `capital` becomes `captial`. For bonus fun. (Hopefully that's just a typo on your part, but we'll cope.)

I'd advise using [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) for this; it's a much more capable package that treats JSON as a fundamental type. (It's even better at it when it comes to querying into the JSON structure.)

```
package require rl_json

set result {{}};  # Literal empty JSON object
dict for {countryID data} $countryDict {
    rl_json::json set result $countryID [rl_json::json template {{
        "population": "~N:population",
        "captial": "~S:capital"
    }} $data]
    # Yes, that was {{ … }}, the outer ones are for Tcl & the inner ones for a JSON object
}
puts [rl_json::json pretty $result]
```

That produces almost exactly the output you asked for, except with different indentation. `$result` is the “production” version of the output that you can work with for further processing, but which has no excess whitespace at all (which is a great choice when you're dealing with documents over 100MB long).

---

Notes:

- The initial JSON object could have been done like this:

  ```
  set result "{}"
  ```

  that would have worked just as well (and been the same Tcl bytecode).
- `json set` puts an item into an object or array; that's exactly what we want here (in a `dict for` to go over the input data).
- `json template` takes an optional dictionary for mapping substitution names in the template to values; that's *perfect* for your use case. Otherwise we'd have had to do `dict with data {}` to map the contents of the dictionary into variables, and that's less than perfect when the input data isn't strictly controlled.
- The contents of template argument to `json template` is itself JSON. The `~N:` prefix in a leaf string value says “replace this with a number from the substitution called…”, and `~S:` says “replace this with a string from the substitution called…”. There are others.

Comment: As you might be able to tell, I don't hold the Tcllib json code in very high regard. rl_json is newer and _much_ better.

Comment: Thanks for confirming  TclLib JSON package is not that easy to work with!  Is rl_json package distributed with standard Tcllib library? if it is not include in standard library, how easy is including this package in a custom application? I know some packages can be downloaded/included straight forwarded but some other packages needs to go through the build process which can be pain especially if you are doing this on a regular basis. I also need to look into this package licensing terms.

Comment: [The license](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json/blob/master/LICENSE) is extremely permissive. But it does need to be built: it's a straightforward `configure --with-tcl=/directory/containing/tclConfig.sh/` + make.

Comment: The license looks to be the Tcl license (including the weird US Government clause that says so little with so many words) with the name of the licensor filed off and replaced.